# Is it possible to retain permissions throughout a request?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have a model that I'm doing a `PATCH` to via a view, which under certain circumstances can mutate my object such that the caller is **not** allowed to further mutate it.

My permission class looks something like this:

```
class MyPermission(BasePermission):

   def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
       if request.user.has_perm("can_change_when_not_done") and obj.status != "done":
           return True
       return super(MyPermission, self).has_object_permission(request, view_obj)
```

This works as expected.

However, it seems that when I patch the object to be "done" (e.g. `{'status': 'done'}` in the payload), it passes through a serializer on the way back which does another permission check, which results in a 403, since the object is now "done". I would like to still get a 200 and a serialized view of what the object looks like now from that request. *Future* mutating requests should result in a 403.

Setting the object to be read-only under "safe" methods (e.g. `GET`) does **not** help, since the original request is still a `PATCH`.

Is there an easy way to achieve what I want, or am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I was mistaken. Permission checks happen only once and very early during a request.

In my case, the issue was that with the signal handler performing the `PATCH` request. Unknown to me at the time, there was another signal handler on that model that at some point did `instance.save()`. This caused my signal handler to run twice, which on the second request obviously resulted in a 403.

After combining the signal handlers (no reason for both to exist), everything works flawlessly. Hope this can help someone in the future!